# Resize google graph after checking the window width using jquery not working

Tags: jquery

I am using google api to get some simple linear graph. I am trying to check the media size using jquery and then load the appropriate graph size. This is mainly to accommodate the graph in mobile devices. The graph loads but doesn't resize. What am I doing wrong?

[Here is the link to the project.](http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/doitt/calender/graph.html)

Here is what I have in js

```
if ($(window).width() <= 750) {
        new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data, {curveType: "linear",
                        width: 350, height: 300,
                        vAxis: {maxValue: 10}}
                );
         } else {
        new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data, {curveType: "linear",
                        width: 500, height: 400,
                        vAxis: {maxValue: 10}}
                );
         }
```

I tried creating a fiddle but apparently fiddle doesnt allow google jsapi

Answer (score 1):

Since no one cared to answer this question I thought I will just answer it myself.

window.innerWidth did the magic for me.

if(window.innerWidth < 760){
      gHeight = 300;
      gWidth = 300;
    }if(window.innerWidth < 540){
      gHeight = 450;
      gWidth = 350;
    } else{
        gHeight = 400;
        gWidth = 600;
     };

Where gHeight and gWidth i am using as drawing parameters for the .draw() from the google chart